# how to ignore null values of a column in Big Query (BQ)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, null

I have a table like below -

| Project_Name | Role1 | Role2 | Role3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Proj1 | R11 |  |  |
| Proj1 | R12 |  |  |
| Proj1 | R13 |  |  |
| Proj1 |  | R21 |  |
| Proj1 |  | R22 |  |
| Proj1 |  |  | R31 |
| Proj2 | R14 |  |  |
| Proj2 |  | R23 |  |
| Proj2 |  | R24 |  |
| Proj2 |  | R25 |  |
| Proj2 |  |  | R32 |

[also the actual table's picture has been attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJPHt.jpg)

So, like this way I have multiple projects(230 projects) & multiple roles columns (almost 15 different roles , but here I used only 3) & under every role column any number of users exist (in between 1 to 100)

I want to ignore this null/blank values for every column at first (last null values should exist) based on every project .(Also if Role1 column has 10 rows and it's the highest for Proj1, then the remaining column also should have 10 values, the only difference is maybe the other column has 3 actual user values & 7 null values, similar way for other column)   The output should be like below -

| Project_Name | Role1 | Role2 | Role3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Proj1 | R11 | R21 | R31 |
| Proj1 | R12 | R22 |  |
| Proj1 | R13 |  |  |
| Proj2 | R14 | R23 | R32 |
| Proj2 |  | R24 |  |
| Proj2 |  | R25 |  |

Thanks in advance. Any kind of help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
with temp_role1 as (
  select Project_Name, Role1, 
    countif(not Role1 is null) over(partition by Project_Name order by Role1) pos
  from your_table
), temp_role2 as (
  select Project_Name, Role2, 
    countif(not Role2 is null) over(partition by Project_Name order by Role2) pos
  from your_table
), temp_role3 as (
  select Project_Name, Role3, 
    countif(not Role3 is null) over(partition by Project_Name order by Role3) pos
  from your_table
)
select * except(pos)
from temp_role1
full outer join temp_role2 using (Project_Name, pos) 
full outer join temp_role3 using (Project_Name, pos) 
where format('%t', (Role1, Role2, Role3)) != '(NULL, NULL, NULL)'
# order by Project_Name, pos
```

If apply to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]

This solution should at least give you an idea to complete your case with all 15+ roles. You can either just repeat/add extra CTEs(temp_roleN) and same amount of JOINS without any extra changes OR you can try to generalize above code and make it more generic - for example using some scripting with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Consider also below approach - it is very easily extended to any numbers of roles - just add them in respective lists: `(Role1, Role2, Role3)` and `('Role1', 'Role2', 'Role3')`

```
select * except(pos)
from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by Project_Name, role order by user) pos
  from your_table
  unpivot (user for role in (Role1, Role2, Role3))
)
pivot (any_value(user) for role in ('Role1', 'Role2', 'Role3'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Hi @Mikhail ,
Thanks a lot for this. I used the 2nd solution 1st and it did work exactly as I want. Really appreciate your quick help. :)

Comment: sure. consider voting up the answers (if not yet) and accept the best one :o)